# Sorting based on first column and highest number in third column

Tags: linux

I have a text file that needs to be sorted, my goal is to only keep the longest sequences in each of my modules. My text file looks like this:

```
1  abc  35
1  def  90
1  ghi  100
2  jui   500
3  yui   500
3  iop   300
```

My goal is to sort unique modules (first column) by keeping highest number from column 3, just like this:

```
1  ghi 100
2 jui   500
3 yui  500
```

So far I checked the sort options but without success, I guess awk could also do it!
I tried:

```
sort -u -k1,1 Black.txt | sort -k3n,3
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sort them based on the third column first and later unique them by first column.

```
sort -r -k 1 -k3n,3 Black.txt|sort -u -k1,1
```

**output**

```
1  ghi  100
2  jui   500
3  yui   500
```

Comment: Hey, so yes my file is tab delimited, but this command does not seem to work, same results as my command, it only picks the first line for each module!

Comment: @user3188922, check the updated answer. I'm assuming you are using bash. I'm able to get the results

Comment: Hey Ashoka, thanks a lot, I am not getting the results I suspect smtg wrong with my file but if you managed I should be able to sort that out! Thanks for your time and effort